# Why did the Losers split in halves?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

When the Losers go to the Well House for the first time, someone asks who wants to keep watch, to which 5 kids raise their hands.

Maybe I missed something (only watched the movie once in the cinema), but why do they then split and only Bill, Eddie and Ritchie go in? I can understand that maybe they didn't want to leave anyone alone, but Beverly didn't even want to stay watch, so why did she stay outside as well?

Comment: All of them are scared at the first time, Bill will surely go for his little brother and Eddie and Ritchie are the more attached to them. So they cant let him go alone. This is only my view. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were obviously very afraid of going into the house.  They said that it would be a good idea if someone kept watch so almost everyone "volunteered" to stay out.

They did not yet realize that Pennywise fed on fear and that together they would be less afraid and not at susceptible to his power.

I agree Beverly staying outside seems to be something of a plot hole.  Eddie says he can't believe he drew the short straw as they are entering the house which suggests that they drew straws.  So even if Beverly, who had less fear of Pennywise than anyone else, offered to go, it stands to reason Eddie and Ritchie drew short straws.